# Specific postgresql server configuration for data analysis purposes

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, data-science

Is there any tips on tuning server's performance using postgresql.conf file in case you use a postgresql database *specifically* for data science department and data analysis purposes? Or performance tuning itself is purpose-agnostic and there is no real difference what you will do with it since 'it is all about extracting data'?

It's a rather obscure question i didn't find an answer for (in miriads of articles on data science topic).

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read the article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far. In your case I would recommend to go through the [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config.html) and try to grasp the general approach for what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: If my answer provided you with a better understanding how to approach what you are trying to achieve you are welcome to give me an upvote.. Enjoy your weekend ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though this is a very general question, I'll try my best to give you a hint or two:

You could first asses the outlines of your requirements, such as:

- are we talking about big-data chunks? (buffer-sizes)
- from how many clients are queries performed? (allowed connections)
- are you using postgresql's internal functions?
- do you need permanent backups or copy tables or db's around?
- etc.,etc.,..

I would recommend you read the article from the official docs on [resource consumption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-resource.html) and the docs on [query-planning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-query.html) as well as [server configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config.html)
 in general.

In case you can't derive a proper approach after reading the docs I can recommend the [pg-forum](https://www.pg-forum.de/). The experienced user 'akretschmer' is a postgresql-pro and might be able to help you if you formulate your question in a detailed and meaningful way ;)

Comment: Thank you for your  comment and for provided guidelines! I'm sorry for not being specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

The same question as OP had occurred to me, and I couldn't find anything about it. Our requirement is simply 2 data scientists accessing the data, slicing it, exploring, etc. Here is our current setup and configuration

- Data: 5 billion rows (~300GB) of AWS cloudwatch 5-minute data
- Hardware: AWS EC2 t2.2xlarge (8 cores, 32GB RAM, 500GB gp2 disk)
- Postgresql version 10
- Modified sections of `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`

```
work_mem = 25GB
maintenance_work_mem = 25GB

max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
```

I'll be more than happy if someone has further suggestions.

Edit: I posted this as a question on [DBA stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237419/postgres-configuration-suitable-for-a-single-300-gb-dataset-5-billion-rows), for further suggestions.